# Importing a row from one Google Sheet to another

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-query, importrange

- **Doc1**: I have individual sheets setup for each Game Week which list the football matches being played on that particular week.
- **Doc2**: I have an individual sheet setup for each team.

I'm looking to pull the scores and team names from a certain row in **Doc1** to **Doc2** based on the team in **Doc2**.

I've worked out how to do this manually but with 20 teams and 38 Game Weeks that is a lot of copying, pasting and changing 30,000+ cells to alter the column reference in.

The "Manual" code I've got working is:

`=importrange("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/xxxxxx/edit#gid=xxxxxx","Game Week 1!A1")`

I'd like to be able to set the team name in **Doc2** and automatically fill in the Game Week rows based on than name.

After some time researching I've come up with this:

`=QUERY(IMPORTRANGE("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/xxxxxxxxxx/edit#gid=xxxxxxxxxx","Game Week 16!A1:A19"),B1,"Select * Row1,Row5")`

But this seems to only want to return numbers and not text as it gives me the error message:

> ...Error
>   Function QUERY parameter 3 expects number values. But 'Select * Row1,Row5' is a text and cannot be coerced to a number.

Any help would be great, as I am at a bit of a dead end.

Below are screenshots of the "Game Week 1" sheet set up and the individual "team" sheet.

[image]

[image]

**Update 1 on the Code**:
`=QUERY(IMPORTRANGE("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/xxxxxxxxxx/edit#gid=xxxxxxxxxx","Game Week 20!A:E"),"Select Col1, Col2, Col3, Col4, Col5 Where Col3, Col5 matches "B1&"")`

This seems like a little step in the right direction but is throwing up an error:

"Error
Formula parse error."

**Update 2**:
`=QUERY(IMPORTRANGE("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/xxxxxxxxxx/edit#gid=xxxxxxxxxx","Game Week 1!A:E"),"Select Col1, Col2, Col3, Col4, Col5 Where Col3, Col5 matches '"&B1&"'")`

The latest tweaks seem to have had some forward progress but I am now receiving this error message:

```
Unable to parse query string for Function QUERY parameter 2: PARSE_ERROR: Encountered " <ID> "Col3 "" at line 1, column 43. Was expecting one of: "(" ... "(" ...
```

Tinkering with a few bits, it seems to be after the 'where' part. As soon as it reads the `Col3, Col5` part it seems to mess up.

**Update 3**:

Realized a small mistake on my part, I was searching Col3, Col5 instead of Col1, Col5.
This still didn't work but then I removed the Col5 so just looking at Col1 and this has returned the correct value.

`=QUERY(IMPORTRANGE("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1dMo6F1CTxAaEx1bS2NEu4kIu5hJTCBbCt13AV2E_f2w/edit#gid=1390527531","Game Week 1!A:E"),"Select Col1,Col2,Col3,Col4,Col5 Where Col1 Matches '"&B1&"'")`

Not sure why I can't check two columns as I've seen other peoples work performing this, may look at changing the whole code to an IF statement(?).

**Update 4**:

CRACKED IT!

`=QUERY(IMPORTRANGE("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/xxxxxxxxxx/edit#gid=xxxxxxxxxx","Game Week 1!A:E"),"Select Col1,Col2,Col3,Col4,Col5 Where Col5 Matches '"&B1&"' or Col1 Matches '"&B1&"'")`

Thanks to Rubén for his valuable input.

Comment: I'm sorry, there was a typo on the formula on my comment, by the other hand, why there is a `**` in B1? What it means / what do you expect as result?

Comment: B1 will be one of the team names from game week 1, I've used ** as a place holder for now.

Comment: It's better to use an actual team name otherwise a simple version of the formula will throw errors and to have a formula that will handle this errors will be a bit harder to understand. Anyway, I edited my answer.

Comment: I use the actual team names in the individual sheets I've created.
adding the additional bits you suggest has seemingly moved this on but I now get another error, which I've added to my main question.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that `B1` has a team name:

`=QUERY(IMPORTRANGE("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/xxxxxxxxxx/edit#gid=xxxxxxxxxx","Game Week 20!A:E"),"Select Col1, Col2, Col3, Col4, Col5 Where Col3, Col5 matches '"&B1&"'")`

Please note the use of `'` to enclose the team name and `&` to concatenate it to the SQL statement

---

As the error message says, the syntax of your second formula is wrong.

The second argument, in this case `B1`, seems to be out of place.
The third argument of the QUERY should be a number.

Maybe you misplaced the arguments, but it's impossible to say as the value of `B1` was not included in the question.

On the other hand `"Select * Row1,Row5"` isn't a valid Google Query Language statement. Please read [QUERY function](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093343?hl=en).

From the above link, here are a couple of samples:

- `QUERY(A2:E6,"select avg(A) pivot B")`
- `QUERY(A2:E6,F2,FALSE)`

Related

- [Unable to parse query string for function Query, when using IMPORTRANGE](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/93002/88163)

Comment: Thanks for getting replying so quickly.
Coding is just a little side hobby I've started recently so I'm still learning.

I'll come back once I have something a bit better.

Comment: @Necrovana I added a link to my answer. If you found this answer helpful consider to accept it (click the tick mark below the triangles and answer score.

Comment: I feel like this, although still doesn't work, is closer to what i'm looking for...

=QUERY(IMPORTRANGE("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/xxxxxxxxx_f2w/edit#gid=xxxxxxxxx","Game Week 1!A1:E19"),"Select Col1,Col5 matches "B1"")

Comment: @Necrovana you forgot to use & operator . If B1 is a number `=QUERY(IMPORTRANGE("docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/xxxxxxxxx_f2w/… Week 1!A1:E19"),"Select Col1,Col5 matches "&B1) ` if B1 is a text `=QUERY(IMPORTRANGE("docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/xxxxxxxxx_f2w/… Week 1!A1:E19"),"Select Col1,Col5 matches '"B1&"'") `. If you need further help, edit your question to add your progress.